# Foundation 4 - trigger Clearing Lightbox

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I want the clearing lightbox to trigger when I click on an image that is not part of list. 
Here is the pic that i would like to trigger the lightbox.

```
 <div id="mainpic" class="large-8 columns">
        <img src='. $url . '>
    </div>
```

And my lightbox.

```
<ul class="clearing-thumbs large-block-grid-5 small-block-grid-2" data-clearing>
<li><a href="' .$url . '"><img class="th" data-caption="'. $description .'" src="' . $url . '"></a></li> </ul>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <a href="#" class="open-clearing"  data-thumb-index="3">Show fourth image in clearing.  </a>
   <script>
   $('.open-clearing').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('[data-clearing] li img').eq($(this).data('thumb-index')).trigger('click');
  });
 </script>
```

I used this one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a way with clearing to manually trigger it to open using the javascript provided with it.  It appears you're going to have to do a small work around, where if your element (image) is clicked, then you can trigger a click event on your clearing thumb.

```
$("#mainpic").on('click', function(){
  $(".clearing-thumbs a").click();
});
```